# Check if $_POST is equal to JSON?

Tags: php, post

I'm trying to verify that a doctor is in the employee list, however my statement seems to always equate to false.

The $response variable contains JSON from a GET request from a rest API. I've verified that the info I enter in my post is in fact in the JSON list. When I ran a foreach on the list, the statement equated to TRUE when it hit the right JSON data. So I am obviously missing something. Would appreciate a hand

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="personal-process.php">
    <label for ="emp_id">Verify Employee </label>
        <input type="text" name="emp_id" id="emp_id">

        <button type="submit">Enter</button>
        
    </form>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['emp_id'])){

    function debug($o){
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($o);
        echo '</pre>';
      }
   
      debug($_POST);
    
    foreach($response['data'] AS $key => $value){
        echo $value ['name'];
        echo '<br>';
    }

    echo $_POST['emp_id'];
    
    if($value['name'] == $_POST['emp_id']){
        

        echo"Success";
    } elseif ($value['name'] != $_POST['emp_id']) {
        echo "Not In the list";
    } 
}
```

Comment: This `if($value['name'] == $_POST['emp_id']){ ... }` should probably go inside the `foreach`

Comment: Additional to what brombeer said: As soon as you find a match, you can break the loop so that you don't needlessly check the list entries after. Also make sure to save that there was a match in a variable. That way you can check if there was or wasn't a match in the logic after the the loop. (that or put the loop in a function and return true on first match; return false after loop)